# FFMPEG Android Compile With libmp3lame

Tags: android, c++, macos, ffmpeg

my os is mac os x

I can compile and use ffmpeg without libmp3lame , and having no problems, I use below command to compile ffmpeg

sudo ./configure

but when I try it with

sudo ./configure --enable-libmp3lame

It returns error ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found

However, I have libmp3lame installed on my system.

I installed libmp3lame using brew install lame

and linked with brew link lame.

when I look into config.log to see error messages I got this

gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DPIC -std=c99 -mdynamic-no-pic -fomit-frame-pointer -fPIC -E -o /tmp/ffconf.V6BXHwIr.o /tmp/ffconf.rMa57AkB.c /tmp/ffconf.rMa57AkB.c:1:10: fatal error: 'lame/lame.h' file not found

So it can not find lame/lame.h but I have lame/lame.h inside /usr/local/include ..

I really stucked on this and searched over internet for many hours,

any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

EDIT =====

I made some progress, now I have compiled ffmpeg witch runs without problems in Android, but I still could not combine it with the libmp3lame

Comment: have you run build command from ndk?

Comment: no I use https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg this library, and for now I try to be able to run it on command line , it gives command line executable with ndk parameter set. I get command line executable without libmp3lame but with libmp3lame i got above errors

Comment: When i built my ffmpeg, this link helped:

http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/

there was another link which helped but i can't seem to find that...

Comment: faced the same issue, i tried to uninstall lame and then try to install it again and it worked for me .

Comment: @SarthakMittal thanks, link seems very useful .

Comment: @shri i tried couple times, but this issue is kinda like that, i am now trying to uninstall lame completely and re-install again. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib to the end of your ./configure string. For me it made the difference. e.g.:

```
./configure --enable-libmp3lame --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/lib
```

I've tried with and without this addition. With it, it works, without it, I get the same error as you.

Comment: will try your solutioh when I try the same thing again, for now I am a bit away from compiling libraries for Android. Thanks anyway, it was a tedious work.